# Cloud Firestore with Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have been looking for a way to use Authentication with Firebase's new Cloud Firestore. I know it's possible, but there is no good guide both in the Documentation and other places.

Could someone please explain how to provide an Authentication UID when `get()`ing data from Cloud Firestore?

Here are my security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /users/{userID} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
  }
}
```

And here is my current code:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid); //lets say "uid" var is already defined
docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
  } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

The structure of my database is just a "users" collection at root, then a document for each user (named after the UID). I want to get the document with the user's UID.

Of course, this gives the error "Missing or insufficient permissions," which is expected, because of the security rules.

This question may seem simple, but if anyone can find some good documentation on this, that would be great!

Comment: Do you want to get all users or only yours.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful). E.g. What does `docRef` point to? Are you signing the user in?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Okay, I edited the question to fill in missing information. Yes, I have done authentication with Google already. I have the UID, I just need to know what to do with it

Comment: @Hareesh I added information on the structure of my database. I have a "users" collection at root, which has documents (named after the UID's). I want to have the user with the corresponding UID to access their own doc.

Comment: ok how you linked your `cities` collection to `users`?

Comment: @Hareesh aah the copypasta is getting me! I just copied this from the firebase website. Let me edit it again... :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was just confused about how UIDs work. I was under the impression that you have to supply a UID and an auth token to database operation.

You don't actually pass in a UID to database operations. The `firebase` object stores authentication state. You can simply sign in ([check the Firebase docs to read how to do this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)), and after the action is completed (use a `.then` promise statement) you can simply do your operation.

Additionally, to have users not sign in every time they visit your app, you can [have the `firebase object's authentication state persistent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence).

Comment: is that even safe to do? Its not really authentication as you have explained :/

Comment: @BMX Yes. Behind the scenes, when you call a sign in method, Oauth ID & refresh tokens are generated. Before executing security rules, Firebase makes sure that the behind-the-scenes JWT token is valid.

Answer (score 9):

Your rule should be inside `match /databases/{database}/documents`

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userID} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
   }
  }
}
```